# Using jQuery delay() with css()

Tags: jquery

Why does delay() work here:

```js
$('#tipper').mouseout(function() {
  $('#tip').delay(800).fadeOut(100);
});
```

But this fails to delay:

```js
$('#tipper').mouseout(function() {
  $('#tip').delay(800).css('display','none');
});
```

// EDIT - here's a working solution

// EDIT 2 - some bugs fixed

```js
$('#tipper').mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#tip').css({'display','none'});
       },800);
});
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) works with the animation (fx) [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). Changing a css property does not work via that mechanism, and thus is not affected by the delay directive.

There is a workaround -- you can inject the property change as a queued operation, like this:

```
$('#tip')
  .delay(800)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
    next(); 
  });
```

Also, you should probably be using `.hide()` instead of `.css('display','none')`.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/DgL3m/

Comment: Hey I know this is an old post but could someone please explain why you have to call the 'next()' function after setting the css. I am using this and it works really well I just want to get my head around how it works

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones, what happens is that the function that you're queuing (in the case above an anonymous function) automatically has passed into it *another function* that will dequeue the next item (moving the queue along). Above I've named that argument "next", although you could name it anything you like. So, inside the anonymous function, "next" is now a function that, when called, advances the queue. If I failed to invoke `next()` at the end of the anonymous function, nothing else in the queue (the `fx` queue) would run.

Comment: @KenRedler thank's for the explanation, it is starting to make sense now.

Comment: I tried it for a relatively small number of elements and was experiencing slow motion behaviour from the browser! any ideas why?

Comment: @YanFoto, set up a test case on jsFiddle so we can take a look.

Comment: what is `next();`  in the last ?

Comment: @KenRedler, it's really a good solution. I am also stuck in that kind of issue and after using your solution my problem get resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

A tiny jQuery extension can help with this. You might call it **qcss**:

```
$.fn.extend({
   qcss: function(css) {
      return $(this).queue(function(next) {
         $(this).css(css);
         next();
      });
   }
});
```

This lets you write:

```
$('.an_element')
   .delay(750)
   .qcss({ backgroundColor: 'skyblue' })
   .delay(750)
   .qcss({ backgroundColor: 'springgreen' })
   .delay(750)
   .qcss({ backgroundColor: 'pink' })
   .delay(750)
   .qcss({ backgroundColor: 'slategray' })
```

This can be a reasonably elegant way to define a chained animation. Note that in this very simple form, qcss only supports a single object argument containing CSS properties. (You’d have to do a bit more work to support `.qcss('color', 'blue')` for instance.)

Here’s [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/41gLwcma/2/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: Very cool! Absolutely neat! Kudos to you. queued css = `qcss` .. ha! I see what you did there! :D This needs to go into next jQuery version.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :)

Comment: Very handy. Thanks for this. I used a variation for property setting...
qcproperty: function (property, val) {
        return $(this).queue(function (next) {
            $(this).prop(property, val);
            next();
        });

Answer (score 12):

Added to *Ken Redler's* answer / suggestion:

> Also, you should probably be using
>   .hide() instead of
>   .css('display','none').

You can do :

```
$('#tip').delay(800).hide(0);
```

The `0` is important here. Passing a value to `.hide()` will implicitly add it to the *fx queue* and therefore, this will work like expected.

Comment: Thanks.  Why is hide() better than setting the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

**test with all browser**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = $("div#1"); // div id=1
    var color = "lightblue"; // color to highlight
    var delayms = "800"; // mseconds to stay color
    $(id).css("backgroundColor",color)
    .css("transition","all 1.5s ease") // you may also (-moz-*, -o-*, -ms-*) e.g
    .css("backgroundColor",color).delay(delayms).queue(function() {
        $(id).css("backgroundColor",""); 
        $(id).dequeue();
    }); 
});
```