# Generic function that show loading icon over any given div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

Is it possible to pass a `div-id` to a function (show) and then show loading image, which covers the entire div & then pass same `div-id`to another function (hide) and hide the loading image shown over the div. I am trying to create a `generic` solution here & not looking for something like this.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loaderDiv').show();
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loaderDiv').hide();
  },
  success: function() {}
});
```

I want to show once loading icon per div. I don't want to show just one big div which covers the entire page. Please help.

Comment: You can make a class in CSS that overlays content the way you want, and then just add/remove that class. One of many options.

Comment: You could create a setting passed to $.ajax(url, settings) that identifies the selector of your target div.  You could then use it in the ajaxsetup to show a loader in place.

Comment: @MariM: How can I tell the css class to overlay over another div in terms of position, height and width?

Comment: @OpenStack You can use `:before` and `after` to set content for a spinning load icon, set its `position` and other attributes similar to that. I can try to come up with an actual answer momentarily.

Comment: Check this out.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349470/how-to-delay-showing-of-progress-if-ajax-takes-less-than-x-seconds -- Specifically my own answer to that question. It shows/hides a local loading icon for ajax calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a setting provided to $.ajax(url, [settings]) you can change the location of a loading div.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var $target = $(settings.targetSelector);
        var $loading = $('#loaderDiv');
        $loading.css($target.position());
        $loading.width($target.width());
        $loading.show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loaderDiv').hide();
    }
});

//then later in a button click or whatever
$.ajax('URL', {
    targetSelector: "#DIV_TO_OVERLAY"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x3f8ntdv/