# AJAX Adding effect before and after request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve is when my user press a button, it request job based on city. I have successfully do that by copying some script.
Now I'm trying to apply some effect.

1. On button click show loading image gif
2. If success it will show a list view
3. If fail it will show No Job in your current city

   ```
   <script>
           // Set City variable
           var city ="Amsterdam";
           //on document ready
           $(document).ready(function(){
          //On button with the id getjob clicked
               $("#getJob").click(function(){
                   //Ajax request and on success call listjob function
                   $.ajax({url:"http://domain.org/job.php?city="+city,
                           success:function(result){
                               var myArr = JSON.parse(result);
                               listJob(myArr);
                           }});    
               });
           });
    function listJob(arr) {
       var out = "";
       var i;
       for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           out += '<li><a href="#jobOne"><i mg src="http://domain.org/img/' + arr[i].image +'"></a><h2>Employer:' +
           arr[i].employer + '</h2><h3>Position: '+  arr[i].jobtitle +'</h3><p>Job Description :' + arr[i].jobdescription + '</p><p>Salary: ' + arr[i].salary  +'</p></li>';
       }
       $("#jobListing").html(out);
   }
   ```

Please Help

Comment: Have you looked into the `beforeSend:` and `complete:` functions of AJAX calls?

Comment: See my own question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349470/how-to-delay-showing-of-progress-if-ajax-takes-less-than-x-seconds for possibly helpful information.

Comment: As @Scott said, you should use the beforeSend and complete function callbacks to achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't even fully understand the whole code hahaha