# toggle css with timeout

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hello I use this code for toggle some css properties:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li#last').toggle(function(){
        $(this).css({"border-bottom": "1px solid #CDCDCD", "-webkit-border-radius": "0px", "border-radius": "0px"});
    }, function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).css({"border-bottom": "0px", "-webkit-border-radius": "0px 0px 5px 5px", "border-radius": "0px 0px 5px 5px"});
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

I added a timeout but now the css doesnt toggle back. Somebody knows how i can fixe it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using setTimeout us `$(this).delay(200).css("CSS HERE");`

Comment: i already tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside the `setTimeout` function is not what you're expecting. You'll need to keep a reference to it outside:

```
$('li#last').toggle(function(){
    $(this).css({"border-bottom": "1px solid #CDCDCD", "-webkit-border-radius": "0px", "border-radius": "0px"});
}, function(){
    var li = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(li).css({"border-bottom": "0px", "-webkit-border-radius": "0px 0px 5px 5px", "border-radius": "0px 0px 5px 5px"});
    }, 200);
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UscQk/2/).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been answered, but what @rickyduck intended was:

```
$("#example").toggle(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff0000")
}, function() {
    $(this).delay(500).queue(function(next){ 
        $(this).css("background-color", "#000") 
        next()
    })
})
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UscQk/15/).

And here's [why the .delay() by itself doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css#5396158).