# jquery - how to queue up a series of css property changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay, jquery-animate

I want to set a series of animation properties - a list of names that are currently invisible but will be marked visible, one right after another, with a set delay of about 100ms between each other. How do I accomplish this with jquery? Essentially, it would be something like this (pseudo-code):

```
for each $(.item) {
$(this).delay(index*100ms).css({'visibility': 'visible'}
}
```

The only thing that might compound this, while most of the elements would have the same class, not all of them would, so an animation queue of some sort would work best.

Comment: Wait, you wan't to something to multiple items or multiple things to just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to do this.

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

> When this statement is executed, the element slides up for 300 milliseconds and then pauses for 800 milliseconds before fading in for 400 milliseconds.

You actually want to do one thing to multiple items, so this is how I'd do that:

```
$.each($(".a"), function(index, value) {
    $(this).delay(index*400).fadeOut(400);
});
```

You were on the right track with your pseudocode, you need to offset each animation by `index * someTime`.

Turns out, `.delay()` actually doesn't work with `css()` so [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396158/219118) an updated solution:

```
$.each($(".a"), function(index, value) {
    $(this).delay(index*400).queue( function(next){ 
        $(this).css('visibility','visible'); 
        next(); 
      });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CLxBf/1)

Comment: Thanks, but this would be occurring to a series of different elements, not different changes to the same element.

Comment: Ah yeah that's what I was unsure about. I'll update my answer in a sec.