# border bottom animation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay

I am trying to create a border bottom animation with jquery, I have tried to no avail. Any Suggestion?

***jQuery code***

```
$("#navigation ul li span").hover(function(){
    $(this)
       .delay(5000)
       .css("border-bottom-color", '#FFF')
       .css("border-bottom-style","solid")
       .css("border-bottom-width","1px");
}

$("#navigation ul li span").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("border","");
});
```

***HTML code***

```
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li data-tab-item="sliders" class="current"><span class="tabcurrent">BRAND ADVERTISING</span></li>
      <li data-tab-item="identity"><span>IDENTITY</span></li>
      <li data-tab-item="print"><span>PRINT</span></li>
      <li data-tab-item="events"><span>EVENTS</span></li>
      <li data-tab-item="web"><span>WEB</span></li>
      <li data-tab-item="bannerAds"><span>BANNER ADS</span></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [borderbottom animation with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174768/borderbottom-animation-with-jquery)

Comment: @JohnConde I tested this code it has merit that there is a problem and jquery and setTimeout are not working for a css animation/effect

Comment: Important! You must include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
#navigation ul li span {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-color: red
}
```

***jQuery***

```
$("#navigation ul li span").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        "border-bottom-width": "2px"
    }, 2000)
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "border-bottom-width": "0px",
        "border-color" : ""
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

and Example of the answer is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gabeDel/XnaXy/)

```
$("#navigation ul li span").hover(function() {
    $(this).delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this)
            .css("border-bottom-color", '#000000')
            .css("border-bottom-style", "solid")
            .css("border-bottom-width", "1px");
    });
});
$("#navigation ul li span").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "");
});​
```

credit::[Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code . This will definitely work. Actually you were using the mosout event, instead of mouseleave().

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#navigation ul li span").live("hover", function () {
            $(this).delay(5000)
   .css("border-bottom-color", 'red')
   .css("border-bottom-style", "solid")
   .css("border-bottom-width", "1px");
        });

        $("#navigation ul li span").live("mouseleave", function (e) {

            if ($(this).css('border-bottom-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
                $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "white");

            }

        });


    });
```

If this will work then please read the use of mouseleave().