# Jquery Delay not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog box that I wish to close after 5 seconds.

I have a delay statement in, but it just closes anyway, without any delay.

Here is the code:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option','buttons',[]).html('File tags and info updated successfully.').delay(5000).dialog('close');
```

Any help with what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: .delay works with only animation methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay` function is for animation, it may be used like this:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
```

You should use simple `setTimeout`:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option','buttons',[]).html('File tags and info updated successfully.');

setTimeout(function () {
  $('#dialog').dialog('close');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/).
Use that to time any jQuery stuff you have.

In your case you must only replace "delay" with "wait":

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option','buttons',[]).html('File tags and info updated successfully.').wait(5000).dialog('close');
```

Have fun!