# myWait(ms) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extend the `$.fn` object in order to have  a *delay* between my jquery commands :

like this working (and quite long) code :

```
$('.d').delay(1000).queue(

function ()
{
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        $(this).dequeue();
}).delay(1000).queue(function ()
{
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $(this).dequeue();
});
```

a working sample is here : [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/urecab/1/edit)

So I tried this :

[**My code at jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/emibod/2/edit)

```
$.fn.myWait = function (ms)
{
    return this.queue(

    function ()
    {
        var _self = this;
        setTimeout(function ()
        { 
            $(_self).dequeue();
        }, ms);
    })
};
```

invoking :

```
$('.d').myWait(1000).css('background-color', 'red').myWait(1000).css('background-color', 'green');
```

But it doesnt work.

What am I doing wrong ?

p.s.
*I did read [**this similar solution**](http://docs.jquery.com/Cookbook/wait), but if I remove the animation part and use only css , it also doesnt work.*

Comment: well , not animations if that's what you're asking.... something like `$("div").myWait(1000).appendTo(...).myWait(1000).css(...)...` ( just an example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery delay() with css()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css)

Comment: @Bergi it is not duplicate. I also stated in my question what is the solution using `queue`. but your duplicate doesnt answer my actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.css()` does not get queued on the animation queue by itself, that's why you needed to put it in a callback in your first snippet. In the second snippet, it is called immediately (even though there's timeout waiting in the queue - just as like you called `.delay()`). Instead, you would need to use an `.animate()` call with a zero-duration.

For allowing the syntax which you wanted, you will need to take a step further. Have a look at the [jQuery timing plugin](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) and [how their magic works](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it in this way. You need to defer execution of those attribute changes, which means you shall store said code in individual functions.