# Use jQuery with CSS3 Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, queue

I need to create a rotator using CSS3 and jQuery. I am using CSS3 to control the fading in and out with jQuery to control when the classes are added. However I cannot get this to work. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4EuFN/1/) of how my current code doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
$('#action-alerts .rotate:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
 $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child')
 .queue( function(next){ 
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').addClass('fadeOut-alert') 
    }).dequeue().delay(1100)
 .queue( function(next){
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').removeClass('fadeOut-alert')
    }).next('.rotate')
 .queue( function(next){ 
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').addClass('fadeIn-alert')
    }).dequeue().delay(1100)
 .queue( function(next){ 
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').removeClass('fadeIn-alert')
    }).dequeue()
    .end()
    .appendTo('#action-alerts');}, 
3000);
```

How would I properly write this to function?

I originally started with the question below:

***ORIGINAL QUESTION***

I am building a rotator of sorts that transitions divs with a nice fade transition. I was originally using nothing but jQuery and it looked nice on desktops but on mobile devices it [flickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423614/jquery-fadein-and-fadeout-causes-flickering). I would like to use CSS3 for mobile devices with jQuery for a fallback but I cannot get the CSS3 + jQuery to control classes to work.

Here is the code I have attempted:

***JS***

```
$('#action-alerts .rotate:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#action-alerts .rotate:first-child').addClass('fadeOut-alert')
     .delay(1100).removeClass('fadeOut-alert')
     .next('.rotate').addClass('fadeIn-alert').delay(1100)
     .removeClass('fadeIn-alert').end().appendTo('#action-alerts');}, 
  3000);
```

Note: The above code is within `$(document).ready(function() { });` Also I do not see the classes being added by jQuery but no errors are thrown.

***CSS***

```
@keyframes fadeIn-alert {
 from {
    opacity:0;
 }  
 to {    
    opacity:1;
 }
}

.fadeIn-alert {
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
   animation-name: fadeIn-alert;
}

@keyframes fadeOut-alert {
 from {
    opacity:1;
 }  
 to {    
    opacity:0;
 }
}

.fadeOut-alert {
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
   animation-name: fadeOut-alert;
}
```

Note: I have omitted vendor prefixes in the code posted here.

***HTML***

```
<div id="action-alerts">

       <div class="quote-holder rotate">
       <div class="grid_10">
       <h3 class="action-box-red"><span class="alert-icon">Text</span></h3>     
       </div>
       <div class="grid_2">
       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="default_button xlarge textcenter red">Read the <br> Report</a>
       </div>
       </div>

       <div class="quote-holder rotate">
       <div class="grid_10">
       <h3 class="action-box-red"><span class="alert-icon">Text</span></h3>     
       </div>
       <div class="grid_2">
       <a target="_blank" href="#" class="default_button xlarge textcenter red">Take <br> Action</a>
       </div>
       </div>
</div>
<!-- MORE HTML AS ABOVE -->
```

Why does my code not work and how do I create the type of effect I am using?

Comment: I've done this, because sometimes CSS transitions provide more functionality/smoothness, etc. The best bet is usually with class names. You don't necessarily have to add classes to the individual elements, either, you can add body classes.

Comment: @JeremyBlalock - Could you provide an example of your code or how you did this?

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass` are not getting queued on the animation queue, but are executed immediately.

Comment: @Bergi - How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @Lynda: See the possible duplicate [Using jQuery delay() with css()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css) (it's the same with `css()` as with `addClass()` etc). Maybe also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15386709/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - Ah I see now but I do not understand very much about `queue`. Would I have to write the code `removeclass` `queue` `addclass` and use `delay` before `queue`? I will try a few things to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Bergi - Edited question for what I attempted that did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.