# Enlarging images from the center with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make four images enlarge and then return to their original size one by one on page load.

You can see my current progress here with the jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XFR7D/8/

```
    $("img").each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).delay(i*1000).animate({

            width:'200px',
            left: '7px',
            top: '76px'


        }, "slow");

        $(this).delay(i*100).animate({

            width:'175px',
            left: '22px',
            top: '90px'


        }, "slow");
});
```

It works, however it's not really smooth and seems to 'quiver' a bit.

If anyone has any advice on how I could get it to be smoother that would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Edit:

I've updated the fiddle with the advice given below however I can not get this to work one by one on each image still.

Comment: Jqueries [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a further parameter: *easing*. Try setting that to "linear": `.animate({...}, 'slow', 'linear')`

Answer (score 0):

Using css3 animations could help you in obtaining a smoother animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/XFR7D/9/

```
img {
    height: auto;
    left: 22px;
    margin: 16px auto 34px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    transition: width ease 1000ms,
                left ease 1000ms,
                top ease 1000ms;

}
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle including my code so it should run it on each element one by one however it doesn't work. Do you have any idea whats going on? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't seem to remove the big class

Answer (score 0):

*I wrote this answer and then realised it would not work in IE9 or below, but I'm posting it anyway. You might be able to use something like [Using jQuery as a Fallback for CSS3 Transitions](http://joshemerson.co.uk/blog/using-jquery-as-a-fallback-for-css3-transitions) for IE9 if you really need to support it.*

CSS3 transitions should generally be smoother because the browser will be natively processing and rendering the changes, rather than jQuery. The browser should also be able to use the GPU to speed up the process. For example:

- [Improving the Performance of your HTML5 App](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/)
- [CSS3: Animations vs. Transitions](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/css3_animations_vs_transitions.htm)
- [Improving HTML5 app performance with GPU accelerated CSS transitions](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2013/01/04/improving-html5-app-performance-gpu-accelerated-css-transitions)

However, delaying the enlarging effect would still need to be done in JavaScript as you already identified. The solution below combines the `<img>` iteration and delay with adding a class which triggers the CSS3 transition. jQuery animation queues are not processed in the same way as `.css()` changes (see [Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css)) so the `.addClass()` needs to be wrapped in a [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) call.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/agacn/) (Webkit/Chrome - for other browsers you will need to add the browser specific prefixed or unprefixed CSS properties for [`transition`](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) and [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform))

**JavaScript**

```
$('img').each(function(i) {
    $(this)
        .delay(1000 * i)
        .queue(function(next) {
            $(this).addClass('scaledUp'); 
            next();
        })
        .delay(500)
        .queue(function(next) {
            $(this).removeClass('scaledUp'); 
            next();
        });
});
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    height: auto;
    left: 22px;
    margin: 16px auto 34px;
    position: relative;
    width: 175px;
    top: 90px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

img.scaledUp {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img width="175" height="268" alt="" src="http://s233308095.websitehome.co.uk/newtkstarley/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/01howwework.png" />
    <img width="175" height="268" alt="" src="http://s233308095.websitehome.co.uk/newtkstarley/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/01howwework.png" />
</div>
```