# Simple Loop JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, setinterval

I know this has been asked several times but I just don't get it.
So here's the case:

```
$ = jQuery;
    var loop = function() {
    $('#content').delay(800).css('background-color', "#B24296");
    $('#content').delay(1600).css('background-color', "#AEB404");
    $('#content').delay(2400).css('background-color', "#04B404");
    loop();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    loop();
```

This setup gives me an "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
I also tried this:

```
var loop = function() {
    $('#content').delay(800).css('background-color', "#B24296", function() {
        $('#content').delay(1600).css('background-color', "#AEB404", function() {
            $('#content').delay(2400).css('background-color', "#04B404");
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(loop,3200);
```

With this code only the first color change happens but the rest of it won't.
So unfortunately none of this does the job of simply changing the background-color from time to time ... Does anyone know a solution or can explain why non of this works?

Edit:
Managed to get it to work like this:

```
function color(t) {
    $("div").delay(t*1).queue(function(n) {
         $('#green').css('background-color', "#B24296");
        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*2).queue(function(n) {
         $('#green').css('background-color', "#AEB404");        n();
    });

    $("div").delay(t*3).queue(function(n) {
         $('#green').css('background-color', "#04B404");
        n();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
       color(500);
    }, 500);
}

color(500);
```

Comment: First one is an infinite loop.

Comment: Tail recursion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion

Comment: you also cannot perform `.delay()` on `.css()`... it just jumps to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, the function loop() calls itself an infinite amount of times resulting in the error you reported.

As for why the css/delay combination doesn't work, as per this answer: [Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css) delay() works with the animation fx queue and has no effect on a css() call.

Again per the solution in [Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css), here is working code for your use case (http://jsfiddle.net/mmSVF/3/):

```
var loop = function() {
  $('#content').delay(800).queue(function(next){
      $(this).css('background-color', "#B24296");
      next();
  }).delay(1600).queue(function(next){
      $(this).css('background-color', "#AEB404");
      next();
  }).delay(2400).queue(function(next){
      $(this).css('background-color', "#04B404");
      setTimeout(loop, 500);
      next();
  });
}

$(function(){
    loop(); 
});
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. Second, this changes the color three times but just once, but i actually want it to change over and over again like an invinite loop, but without causing the error

Comment: You can add `setTimeout(loop, 500);` before the 3rd call to next() to achieve this result. I'll make this edit to the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much! This is the first solution I understand!