# How to delay a jquery event that isn't an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, delay

I have a jquery event that I want to occur only after a certain amount of time. Apparently, `delay` only works with animation events. Is there an alternative to `delay` I can use in this situation?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".opacity").delay(1000).css({"opacity": ".5",}).delay(1000).css({"opacity": "1",});
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css

Comment: Note that using `.css()` isn't an "event".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), no need to use the delay function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".opacity").css({
      "opacity": ".5",
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".opacity").css({
        "opacity": "1",
      })
    }, 1000)
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="opacity">opacity</div>
```

If you want to use the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay) function, then you can add an entry to the delay queue using [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback) add your code there

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".opacity").delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).css({
      "opacity": ".5",
    })
    next();
  }).delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).css({
      "opacity": 1,
    })
    next();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="opacity">opacity</div>
```