# background-image not fading in properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

I've been working on a loading screen for a one-page website, the loading screen is nothing more than a svg logo drawing itself out which works perfectly fine, but once the 'loading' is done i fade out the loading screen and fade in the content of the website.

It works fine except for the fact that when the content fades in it shocks really bad because of the background-image, i know that this is not the background-image loading itself because the whole reason there is a loading screen at all is to give the website time to load all of the images, so for some reason the fadein is not working properly.. perhaps it's the way i set up all the animations, have a look:
(i use jquery and animate.css for the fades)

JQuery:
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#Builds").children().addClass("animatedLogo");

```
  setTimeout(function() {

    $(".loadingLogo").addClass("fadeOut");

    setTimeout(function() {

      $(".loadingScreen").addClass("fadeOut");

      setTimeout(function() {

        $(".loadingScreen").css('display', 'none');

        setTimeout(function() {

          $("body").css('overflow-y', 'auto');

          $(".contentWrapper").addClass("fadeIn").show();
          $("header").addClass("fadeIn").show();

          setTimeout(function() {

            $("body").css('background-color', "#fff");

          }, 500)
        }, 500)
      }, 500)
    }, 500)
  }, 3400)
```

Html:

```
 <div class="loadingScreen animated">
        <div class="loadingLogo animated">
            <svg>
              //svg logo
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="contentWrapper animated">
       @yield('content')
 </div>
```

so i pretty much already know that there is something wrong with the way that i am doing this, perhaps doing it like this is to performance heavy? any suggestions on how to do this differently are much appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is the shortest version because the question includes the whole process of this animation, i specifically said "any suggestion on how to do this differently are appreciated", so yeah.. thx for commenting though.. i guess

Comment: hi, why won't you use `$.delay()` from jQuery? will helps you to do things like this ... 
`$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );`

Comment: Without a functioning demo how can we tell what's actually happening?

Comment: This is not a complete version as you do not provide the HTML or CSS to work with. How can anyone help you debug your issue? Additionally, do you know what a `callback` function is? Or how to use jQuery's `animate` function? Did you read Animate.css documentation to learn about the `animationEnd` event, or extending jQuery with Animate's behavior? Any of these things would help you write this better. Nested `setTimeout`s is never a good idea.

Comment: @Paulie_D i explained the problem didn't i? i already know it's performance related so i was just asking for an alternative to animations with animate.css

Comment: @Ganov13 jquery fades are not as smooth as animate.css though so.. :p

Comment: @J.Titus will do! and didn't know that nesting settimeout isn't a good idea, care to explain though? :/

Comment: @SimonRook was just talking about replacing setTimeOut  by $.delay... it  was not about fadin/out or Css :D. Up to you.

Comment: @Ganov13 ooh okay i'll take a look at it, tought delay only worked with .animate though? tyvm!

Comment: @SimonRook this Stackoverflow answer'll help you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css
if you steel plan t use `$.Css()` with `$.delay()`

Comment: Jesus someone downvoted my question for no reason whatsoever, got nothing better to do -.-

Comment: ik heb je question geupvote man maar ik weet wel waarom je downvote hebt gekregen haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to display a loading screen until your page content loads, you can replace your existing code with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(images/loader-64x/Preloader_2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

Note: Change background url in this css. Replace it with the your svg file which is going to be shown as loading image.

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

In this scenario, you don't need to fade In your page content manually. As soon as page loads all the content and window is ready, your loading screen will automatically fade out and your page will be visible to users. Your page's Background image will also not look bad, because it will be already loaded on screen.

You can [Click here](http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/) for further details.

Give a try to this approach and hope this will help you to overcome your issue.

Comment: thank you for answering! i will definitly try this out!

Comment: it worked! appreciate the help, thank you! problem was i wasn't using position fixed, i can now fade out without a problem thanks again!

Comment: That's great..!! :-)