# Jquery Delay and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i [have/want] to make a Storytelling Website like:

http://www.bizbrain.org/coffee/

1) Would you guys creat every Object in CSS or would you do it Frame by Frame in Photoshop?

2) Why doesnt the Delay work? (Yes i tested a Higher delay aswell like 5000)(Code Below **the Line**)

3) How do i bind the stylesheet.css File if i move it to the \misc\style Folder?
I tried:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\misc\style\stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".\misc\style\stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".misc\style\stylesheet.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/misc/style/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./misc/style/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".misc/style/stylesheet.css">
```

_________________________________________________________________________________ 
^**the Line**

**test.js**

```html
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var n = 1; 
 for(i = 1; i < 30; i++){
  changePicture();
 }
 function changePicture(){
  n+=1;
  $('.p').delay(33).css('background-image', 'url("misc/bilder/'+n+'.png")');  
 } 
});
```

**stylesheet.css**

```html
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 height: 1000%;
}
.p{
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 padding: 25%;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
 background-image: url("misc/bilder/1.png");    
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\misc\style\stylesheet.css">
<title>Evolution des Menschen</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="p"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="misc/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="misc/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can tell from the Code i have no Webdesign experience
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var delay = 33;
  changePicture(1, 30, 'misc/bilder', '.png')

  function changePicture(next, last, path, extension){
    if (next <= last){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.p').css('background-image', 'url("' + path + '/' + next + extension + '")');
        next += 1;
        changePicture(next, last, path, extension)
      }, delay);
    }   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) CSS for sure. Frame by frame is not HTML5. Is just a video... With CSS you have control of every object, and you can move them in multiple ways with conditionals depending on device width, other element positions, mouse positions and whatever.

2) Because `css()` in jQuery is not *animated dependant*. It just gets applied instantly to the object that is called. To `css()` work with `delay()` check this answer: [Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css)

3) You have to remove the starting dot. Check the address of your your `test.js` file under your `index.html`. Do the same with your `stylesheet.css`.

Comment: 1) would you recommend a programm like photoshop cs6 to create the css objects? (thats the first photoshop  where you can export things as css i think) 3) i tried all the thinks i posted could you write exact what i should write?

Comment: There is nothing like `css objects`. There are HTML elements, and CSS properties. For example, the website that you shown are simple png images set as backgrounds using CSS on HTML elements (`div`, `span`, etc). If you don't know nothing about designing websites, you should start by learning a bit about HTML before doing such a complex work like this. If you don't, you will face tons of problems that you will not be able to solve. And worse, you will now know what the hell are you doing when copying and pasting code from tutorials and websites around Google, like your `stylesheet.css` problem.

Comment: 2) shouldnt that work then? it waits the written 3 sec. but jumps to the last pic instant after that aswell  http://pastebin.com/w120KXSs

Comment: *EDIT* Rude guy here :-(

Comment: Sorry for being rude. Had a bad day and my bad day is not your fault, obviously.

Comment: Let's see, was going to write 3) You should remove the starting dot. Look closely on how you load your `test.js` file in your `index.html`. You write as src as `"misc/js/test.js"`, but in your `stylesheet.css` you write your href as `".misc/style/stylesheet.css"`. You have written a dot before the main. Thing that you don't do in your other line that works. That's the difference.

Comment: 2) Yes, that *ALMOST* works. You are facing a different problem here. Is a common Javascript programming problem for newbies. Let me explain:

Comment: You have a loop. A loop than runs 30 times. I suppose that you understand that those 30 times that the loop runs are ran *instantly*. Inside each loop you apply a `jQuery delay()`. The thing is that you run the `delay()` command *instantly* too, but jQuery is smart enough to queue the callbacks. The problem here is that your `n+=1` is also ran instantly, so, before the first delay is ran, `n` is already 30 (remember that the loop is ran instantly).

Comment: You must increase `n` inside the callback. Or doing it *the right way*, you must reference `n` inside the callback as a function argument. But that's more difficult to understand for a non-experienced programmer, so better do it the first way, simply moving `n+=1` inside the callback.