# Change multiple divs background colour one after the other and then back to normal (repeat)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few divs and each div has a different background color.

I need to change the background colour of each div to grey and then show the original background colour and then move to the next div and do the same. And i need this to repeat.

I have put together this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j52dhetq/3/) which should explain what I'm trying to do.

The issue that i have is that my code changes all the divs background colour to grey all at the same time and it doesn't repeat either!

This is my code:

```
$(".box").each(function(index) {

$(this).delay(400*index).css('background-color','#ccc');

});
```

Could someone please advice on this?

I also tried the suggested "duplicated" code and this still changes all the backgrounds all at the same time:

```
$('.box')
  .delay(800)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
    next(); 
  });
```

also tried this:

```
$('.box')
  .delay(800)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).delay(400*index).css('background-color','#ccc');
    next(); 
  });
```

and this:

```
$('.box')
  .delay(800).delay(400*index)
  .queue(function (next) { 
    $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
    next(); 
  });
```

I need to change the background colours one after the other!

EDIT:

ok this is the modified version of the code based on George's code in the comments:

```
$(".box").each(function(index) {

var color = $(this).css('background-color');
$(this).delay(400*index).queue(function (next) { 
     $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');

    next(); 

  });

 $(this).css('background-color',color);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j52dhetq/5/

The issue with that is that it is not switching back to its original background colour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery delay() with css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396119/using-jquery-delay-with-css)

Comment: @George, view my edit plz.

Comment: The duplicate was a suggestion. You still need to keep your `400*index` for the delay.

Comment: @George, i did.. it doesn't work.

Comment: [Are you sure about that?](https://jsfiddle.net/j52dhetq/4/)

Comment: @George, ARRHH... so that's how its done! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes. I am not sure about the values you need. But it will help you for transitions. Hope this helps!!

```js
$(".box").each(function(index) {
$(this).delay(400*index).queue(function (next) { 
$(this).css('transition-timing-function','ease-in-out');
     $(this).css('animation','progress ' +400*index+'ms');

    next(); 

  });

});
```

```css
@keyframes progress {
   50% { background-color: #ccc;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:10px;">
    <div class="box" style="background-color:red; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:orange; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:yellow; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:green; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:blue; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:purple; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:navy; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="background-color:white; width:12%; height:10px;display:inline-block;"></div>
     
     </div>
```