# jquery - increase timeout interval with each iteration of .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger an animation on a list of elements and have each iteration increase in delay a bit. I have what I've done so far here:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/9j06qxu9/1/)

```
var timer = 1000;

$('div').each(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div').animate({
                width:200,
                height:200,
                opacity:1
            }, 1000);
        }, timer);
        timer += 1000;
});
```

There aren't any errors and it technically works, but they all animate at the same time. I know it's very similar (practically identical) to this, [similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202403/how-to-add-pause-between-each-iteration-of-jquery-each), but for some reason it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the index parameter to increase the animation as you go.

Also, you're targeting **all** the elements inside the loop, use the second parameter instead, which is the element currently iterated over

```
$('div').each(function(i, elem){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(elem).animate({
                width:200,
                height:200,
                opacity:1
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000 * i);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9j06qxu9/2/)

jQuery also has a `delay()` method that can be used for animations

```js
$('div').each(function(i, elem){
    $(elem).delay(i * 1000).animate({
        width   : 200,
        height  : 200,
        opacity : 1
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:#f00;"></div>
<div style="background:#000;"></div>
<div style="background:#ccc;"></div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much. Very useful information too. I tried using `delay()` at one point, but wasn't adding it in the right spot.