# How to not AddClass to elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add Class to some element not at once? I am looking for a way to add the class to the element with some delay(one by one) instead of applying the class to all at once.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('blue');
    });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
```

Comment: So, you’d use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Which of those have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add pause between each iteration of jQuery .each()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202403/how-to-add-pause-between-each-iteration-of-jquery-each)

Comment: you can try using closure and setInterval with delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use setTimeout:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").each(function(index){
      const element = this;
      // Delay in ms
      const delay = index * 1000;

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).addClass('blue');
      }, delay);

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet. It does nothing but break loop after each element.

```js
$("button").click(function(e){
    $("p").not('.blue').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('blue');
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
<p>App </p>
```